# Simulate mouse and keyboard inputs to a window in the background without interrupting actual user input python?

Tags: python-3.x

So here's my problem.  I've looked at `pyautogui`, and `pywinauto` so far.  In terms of what I would like to do, I would like to simulate mouse and keyboard inputs to a non-active window that the user is currently not using, and not actually interrupt what the user is doing.  In `pyautogui`, it forces actual mouse movement which makes it impossible for me to do other tasks while such a script is running.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Your question is worded well for a first question, and is clear and concise.

Comment: So what window do you want to manipulate? What app is it?

Comment: Let's say something like a windowed game or something of that nature/

Comment: Ok... I'll have to look into this, but my gut says pure python might not cut it...

Comment: That's fine, my goal here is to know whether or not I can do it, and avoid spending too much time looking for an answer that may not be there for a learner who isn't able to make the solution myself.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Initial ideas/searches are turning up nothing that will run in the background the way you want... I'm actually thinking that the best way could be to download some malware source code that does something similar, and reverse engineer it, cause I can't find an easily available solution.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help!  My end goal for my career is cyber security so hopefully one day I can manage to do that.

Comment: Cyber sec is always a good field to head for - the salarys are enormous in the private pen testing sector